# I am trying to pass a object or type to the a class that accepts a generic type

Tags: .net, generics, c#-4.0

```
Type hai = Type.GetType("TestStringObject", true);
var obj = (Activator.CreateInstance(hai));
tata = CreateClass<obj>();
```

I want to do something like this, but the generic class is not recognizing obj as an object or type?

Can i do this?

Comment: Can you provide the code for `CreateClass` and provide the error messages you are receiving, if any?

Comment: replace CreateClass with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<> any class that accepts a generic object....

Comment: Is "TestStringObject" a class in your project? Are you using `GetType` because you don't know the type until runtime?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are using `obj` as a type, when it is an instance of an object. A generic type argument must be a class, not an instance or a type, and must be known at compile-time.

If `TestStringObject` is a class in your project, you could use that as the generic type argument like so:

```
tata = CreateClass<TestStringObject>();
```

If you do not know the type at compile-time, you can create a generic method to match the unknown type (provided as a string) at runtime and invoke your generic method that way. In the example below, I'm going to assume that there is a class named `TestStringObject` that has a generic method named `CreateClass`; your exact situation may vary, but this should accomplish what you need:

TestStringObject:

```
namespace Test
{
    class TestStringObject
    {
        public void CreateClass<T>()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CreateClass Invoked");
        }
    }
}
```

Elsewhere...

```
// Get the type of the unknown type, provided here as a string.
Type type = Type.GetType("Test.TestStringObject", true);
// Create an instance of the unknown type.
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
// Get a reference to the 'CreateClass' generic method info.
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("CreateClass");
// Get a reference to a version of the generic method that accepts the unknown type as a generic type argument.
MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
// Invoke the generic method of the unknown type.
genericMethod.Invoke(obj, new object[] { });
```

Please take note of the namespace, which must be included when invoking `GetType` as it requires a fully-qualified name.